# Category archive is displaying all posts rather than the specific category

Tags: categories, loop, archives

Here is my loop code for index.php .  I do not have an archive or category.php right now.  This is very basic.

```
$temp = $wp_query;
global $wp_query;    
$wp_query = new WP_Query();

$wp_query->query('posts_per_page=20'.'&paged='.$paged);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
```

I have about 10 posts split up into different categories.

When I click /category/category-name it just lists all posts rather than filtering by category.

Can someone help me out if they know the solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the query that loads with the page (which you saved to $temp) - why not just use the one that loads with the page:

```
while(have_posts()) : the_post();

// put the post here

endwhile;
```